# How to make Excel VBA macro run much faster

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to VBA and am trying to create a dashboard with a really long VBA code. The code is used to look-up values from multiple sheets. The code itself works, but runs incredibly slowly and freezes the Excel sheet. Any tips on how to make the code run faster would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub CreateCostReport()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'STEP 1: Start window ask for confirmation

Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString
Msg = "Update can take several minutes. Do you want to update the data?"    'Edit message.
Style = vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2                                          'Define buttons.
Title = "NOTICE"                                                            'Define title
Help = "DEMO.HLP"                                                           'Define Help file.
Ctxt = 1000                                                                 'Define topic context.
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)                            'Display message.
If Response = vbYes Then                                                    'User chose Yes.
    MyString = "Yes"                                                        'Perform some action.
Else                                                                        'User chose No.
    MyString = "No"                                                         'Perform some action.
End If

If MyString = "Yes" Then
    
    'STEP 2: Initiation
    
    'Parameters of phase overview sheet
    
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=4                             'Expand all the hidden levels
        
    cur_sheetname_1 = ActiveSheet.Name                                      'Name of the phase overview sheet
    
    cur_phase_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("phase_1").Value
    
    col_supplier_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("supplier_1").Column
    col_contract_no_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("contract_no_1").Column
    col_item_desc_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("item_desc_1").Column
    col_unit_price_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("unit_price_1").Column
    col_unit_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("unit_1").Column
    
    col_budget_value_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("budget_value_1").Column
    col_budget_value_auto_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("budget_value_auto_1").Column
    
    col_order_value_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("order_value_1").Column
    col_invoice_value_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("invoice_value_1").Column
    
    col_quantity_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("quantity_1").Column
        
    col_pid_l1_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("pid_l1_1").Column                        'Column of PID Level 1
    col_pid_l2_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("pid_l2_1").Column                        'Column of PID Level 2
    col_pid_l3_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("pid_l3_1").Column                        'Column of PID Level 3
    col_pid_desc_de = ActiveSheet.Range("pid_desc_de").Column
    col_pid_desc_en = ActiveSheet.Range("pid_desc_en").Column
    col_pid_l4_1 = col_pid_l3_1
    
    cur_row_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("first_row_1").Row                           'First row of phase overview sheet
    
    'Parameters of data export sheet
    
    cur_sheetname_2 = ActiveSheet.Range("datasheet_costs").Value               'Name of the data export sheet
    
    col_phase_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("phase_2").Column
    
    col_supplier_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("supplier_2").Column
    col_contract_no_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("contract_no_2").Column
    col_item_desc_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("item_desc_2").Column
    col_unit_price_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("unit_price_2").Column
    col_unit_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("unit_2").Column
    col_ve_desc_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("ve_desc_2").Column
    
    col_order_value_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("order_value_2").Column
    col_invoice_value_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("invoice_value_2").Column
    
    col_order_quantity_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("order_quantity_2").Column
    col_invoice_quantity_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("invoice_quantity_2").Column
    
    col_invoice_balanced_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("invoice_balanced_2").Column
    
    col_pid_l4_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Range("pid_l4_2").Column
    
    'Paramters of budget sheet
    
    cur_sheetname_3 = ActiveSheet.Range("datasheet_budget").Value
    
    col_phase_3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).Range("bdg_phase").Column
    col_item_desc_3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).Range("bdg_item_desc").Column
    col_quantity_3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).Range("bdg_quantity").Column
    col_unit_3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).Range("bdg_unit").Column
    col_unit_price_3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).Range("bdg_unit_price").Column
    col_budget_value_3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).Range("bdg_budget_value").Column
    
    col_pid_l4_3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).Range("bdg_pid_l4").Column
    
    'STEP 3: WHILE LOOP to copy data from data export sheet into phase overview sheet
    
    count_1 = 0                                                              'Count condition to end WHILE
    
    While count_1 <> 20
    
        If Len(ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1, col_pid_l4_1).Value) <> 10 Then  'Only PID level 4 code has 10 characters
        
            count_1 = count_1 + 1                                            'Empty row
            cur_row_1 = cur_row_1 + 1
            
        Else
            
            pid_l4_code_1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_1).Cells(cur_row_1, col_pid_l4_1).Value
            
            'STEP 3.1: Open budget sheet and filter
            
            If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_1).Cells(cur_row_1, col_budget_value_auto_1) > 0 Then
            
                        'Open data export sheet
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).Activate
                        
                        'Filter after PID level4 code & phase code
                        ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AZ").AutoFilter Field:=col_pid_l4_3, Criteria1:=pid_l4_code_1
                        ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AZ").AutoFilter Field:=col_phase_3, Criteria1:=cur_phase_1
        
                        'Copy filtered data
                        Range("A1").Select
                        Range("A1:AZ1").Select
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        Selection.Copy
                        
                        'Add a temporary sheet for data transport and store the data temporarily
                        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        temp_sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
                        
                        'Cancel filter in the data export sheet which was done in the last action
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).Activate
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_3).ShowAllData
                        
                        'Open phase overview sheet to do data transport
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_1).Activate
                                                                                          
                        'Initiation for data transport
                        temp_row = 2
                        
                        'Loop for data transport
                        While ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_pid_l4_3).Value <> ""
                                                                
                            command_string = CStr(cur_row_1 + 1) + ":" + CStr(cur_row_1 + 1)
                            Rows(command_string).Select
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                            
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_item_desc_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_item_desc_3)
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_quantity_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_quantity_3)
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_unit_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_unit_3)
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_unit_price_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_unit_price_3)
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_budget_value_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_budget_value_3)
                                                        
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_pid_l4_1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1, col_pid_l4_1)
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_pid_desc_de) = ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1, col_pid_desc_de)
                            ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_pid_desc_en) = ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1, col_pid_desc_en)
                                
                            cur_row_1 = cur_row_1 + 1
                            temp_row = temp_row + 1
                            
                        Wend
                        
                        'Delete the temporary sheet
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(temp_sheetname).Delete
                        'Initiation
                        'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_1).Activate
            
            End If
            
            'STEP 3.2: Open data export sheet and filter
            'Open data export sheet
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Activate
            'Filter after PID level4 code & phase code
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AZ").AutoFilter Field:=col_pid_l4_2, Criteria1:=pid_l4_code_1
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AZ").AutoFilter Field:=col_phase_2, Criteria1:=cur_phase_1
            'Check if there are data after filter, sum of orders
            sum_order_2 = 0
            vArr = Split(Cells(1, col_order_value_2).Address(True, False), "$")     'Turn column nummber into letter
            range_order_2 = vArr(0)                                                 'Turn column nummber into letter
            command_string = range_order_2 + ":" + range_order_2
            Set sum_range = ActiveSheet.Range(command_string)
            sum_order_2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sum_range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            'Check if there are data after filter, sum of invoices
            sum_invoice_2 = 0
            vArr = Split(Cells(1, col_invoice_value_2).Address(True, False), "$")   'Turn column nummber into letter
            range_invoice_2 = vArr(0)                                               'Turn column nummber into letter
            command_string = range_invoice_2 + ":" + range_invoice_2
            Set sum_range = ActiveSheet.Range(command_string)
            sum_invoice_2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sum_range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            
            If (sum_order_2 > 0) Or (sum_invoice_2 > 0) Then
                    
                        'Copy filtered data
                        Range("A1").Select
                        Range("A1:AZ1").Select
                        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        Selection.Copy
                        
                        'Add a temporary sheet for data transport and store the data temporarily
                        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
                        ActiveSheet.Paste
                        temp_sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
                        
                        'Cancel filter in the data export sheet which was done in the last action
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Activate
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).ShowAllData
                        
                        'Open phase overview sheet to do data transport
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_1).Activate
                                                                                          
                        'Initiation for data transport
                        temp_row = 2
                        
                        'Loop for data transport
                        While ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, 1).Value <> ""
                                                                
                            ve_desc_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_ve_desc_2).Value
                            ve_desc_2_type = Left(ve_desc_2, 6)
                            
                            If ve_desc_2_type <> "XXXXXX" Then
                        
                                command_string = CStr(cur_row_1 + 1) + ":" + CStr(cur_row_1 + 1)
                                Rows(command_string).Select
                                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                                
                                ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_supplier_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_supplier_2)
                                ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_contract_no_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_contract_no_2)
                                ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_item_desc_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_item_desc_2)
                                ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_unit_price_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_unit_price_2)
                                ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_unit_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_unit_2)
                                
                                'Check order line or invoice line
                                'main_string = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_item_desc_2)
                                'sub_string = ". AZ" 'Sign for invoice line
                                
                                invoice_typ = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_invoice_balanced_2)
                                
                                If invoice_typ = "True" Then
                                    ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_invoice_value_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_invoice_value_2)
                                    ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_quantity_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_invoice_quantity_2)
                                Else
                                    ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_order_value_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_order_value_2)
                                    ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_quantity_1) = Sheets(temp_sheetname).Cells(temp_row, col_order_quantity_2)
                                End If
                                                        
                                ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_pid_l4_1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1, col_pid_l4_1)
                                ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_pid_desc_de) = ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1, col_pid_desc_de)
                                ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1 + 1, col_pid_desc_en) = ActiveSheet.Cells(cur_row_1, col_pid_desc_en)
                                
                                cur_row_1 = cur_row_1 + 1
                                
                            End If
                            
                            temp_row = temp_row + 1
                            
                        Wend
                        
                        'Delete the temporary sheet
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(temp_sheetname).Delete
                        
                        'Initiation
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_1).Activate
                        count_1 = 0
                        cur_row_1 = cur_row_1 + 1
    
                Else
                
                        'Cancel filter in the data export sheet which was done in the last action
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_2).Activate
                        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
                        
                        'Initiation
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_1).Activate
                        count_1 = 0
                        cur_row_1 = cur_row_1 + 1
                    
                End If
                            
        End If
    
    Wend
                        
    'Save data
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cur_sheetname_1).Cells(Range("report_date").Row, Range("report_date").Column) = Date
    MsgBox "Finished!"

End If

End Sub
```

I thought of getting the Active out, but i don't know how to replace it.